# Static variable in singleton

Tags: objective-c, ios, variables, static, singleton

I have a singleton and want to create internal flag variable that should indicate that singleton was "released" and when I getting singleton instance its should reinitialize itself.

For this case I decide to use static variable

```
static BOOL wasReleased = NO;
```

and set it to "YES" in destroy function:

```
- (void)destroy
{
    wasReleased = YES;
    ...release internal singleton resources...
}
```

But when I try to get singleton instance this variable value is always "NO" so internal resources never reinitialized after releasing:

```
+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance
{
    if (sharedCoordinator == nil)
    {
        sharedCoordinator = [[super alloc] init];
        [sharedCoordinator initialize];
    }

    if (wasReleased) 
    {
        [sharedCoordinator initialize];
    }

    return sharedCoordinator;
}
```

My understanding of this situation maybe wrong, please clarify its for me.

Comment: You mean it's `NO` _after_ you send `destroy`?

Comment: Do you call destroy manually? because I guess otherwise the object will just never be destroyed

Comment: Josh Caswell, yes, its value is `NO` after sending `destroy`. I'm changing value of "wasReleased" only in this two situations in question above. I check `wasReleased` value inside `destroy`, so it is `YES` how I'm expected, but after it is not.


Joerg Simon, yes, I'm calling "destroy" manually, I'm using breakpoints to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not address your immediate concern, but you should reconsider your design. Destroying a singleton is not a good idea. If you are trying to free up significant resources (images, videos, etc.) you can make the actual methods on the singleton responsible for re-instantiating them.

The following will not work as expected:

```
- (id)initSomeClassUsingTheSingleton
{
  mySingletonVariable = [MySingleton sharedInstance];
}

- (void)someOtherFunctionOccuringAfterDestroy
{
  [mySingletonVariable aMethodOnTheSingleton];
}
```

This is a perfectly valid way to use a singleton, yet in your case you cannot do it. Instead your singleton should have methods like the following:

```
- (void)aMethodOnTheSingleton
{
  //if resources for method not allocated
    // .. allocate

  // do the rest
}
```

Comment: Hi, David V, thanks for answer. Of course I'm not want to release singleton instance, only resources incapsulated in singleton. Only one problem is that I can't understand reason why my bool flag not keeping its value.
As I understand it, your `resourcesForMethodNotAllocated` has the same meaning as my `wasReleased`.

Comment: I edited the post to clarify that if(resourcesForMethodNotAllocated) was only conceptual. It may be the same as the wasReleased boolean, though I would suggest making it an instance variable. It may also be different if different methods need different resources. I don't know which your problem calls for.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your static `wasReleased` instance variable and make it a property of `MySingleton` class (don't forget to synthesize it)

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL wasReleased;
```

then in the `-destroy` method:

```
- (void)destroy
{
    self.wasReleased = YES;
    //...release internal singleton resources...
}
```

then (remove your static ivar `sharedCoordinator` - I suppose you have one)

```
+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance
{
    static MySingleton *sharedCoordinator = nil;
    if (!sharedCoordinator)
    {
        sharedCoordinator = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
        [sharedCoordinator initialize];
    }

    if (sharedCoordinator.wasReleased) 
    {
        [sharedCoordinator initialize];
        sharedCoordinator.wasReleased = NO; //If you are not doing it in the -initialize method
    }

    return sharedCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this will help?

Comment: Because, declaring a static instance variable (for both cases with `wasReleased` and `sharedCoordinator`)  and using it in a class method doesn't make sense, because in the class method you are not in the scope of the instance. The class method cannot access instance variables, but you can access them from an instance...

Comment: It's not an instance variable -- it couldn't be declared like that if it was -- and there's no such thing as a "static instance variable". It's a `static` file-level variable (which is accessible in a class method); this is the workaround in ObjC for "class member variables".

Comment: Yes there isn't - you're right.. I didn't provide a good explanation...

Comment: But anyway I don't think you can change the static wasReleased from an instance method - it's just not in that scope... I haven't tried the code I posted, but I am pretty sure it will work...

Comment: Your code will work, it just doesn't seem to change anything significant. You can use a file-level variable from any method -- instance _or_ class -- or function in that file.

Comment: It changes the instance variable behind the property `wasReleased` when calling `destroy` method of the static instance of the class which is enough to tell if you have released the internal resources of the static instance of `MySingleton` class. And one addition, this code would have a bug if the `-initialize` method does not set `self.wasReleased = NO;`

Comment: The variable zakhej is using does the same thing. You're just storing that information in a different place, but those two places should be equivalent for this functionality.

Comment: Hmm you're right, just tested his solution and it works as expected, he is probably not calling the destroy method :)

Comment: And again there is my mistake... Sorry guys for wasting your time.
I'm create more complicated system than this must be, so tangled myself. `Destroy` was called but not at the time that I was expecting. Solution in question is worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding of this situation maybe wrong, please clarify its for
>   me.

Why are you using a singleton in the first place? A singleton should never need to be released or re-initialized. If you need to do those things, it's very likely that you should simply create a new instance of your class whenever you need one.

Also, it would be a good idea to avoid using `-initialize` as an instance method name as that could easily be confused with the class method `+initialize` that every class has.